# What order does rsyslog process configuration files in /etc/rsyslog.d?

Tags: rsyslog

I have several configuration files in /etc/rsyslog.d, e.g., 01-templates.conf, 02-error-logs.conf, 03-system-logs.conf, and have the following line in my /etc/rsyslog.conf file

```
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

What order do the /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf files get loaded in? Where is this documented? I read the [Rsyslog configuration](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/index.html) page but did not see it.

Comment: Please let me know if you find out the documentation for the same. I am also curious to find the official documentation for this.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://rsyslog-users.1305293.n2.nabble.com/etc-rsyslog-d-conf-tp7580221p7580222.html) and [this post](http://rsyslog-users.1305293.n2.nabble.com/Processing-order-question-tp7591898p7591900.html) to the rsyslog-users mailing list, it's processed in alphabetical order.

But with the exception of some 7.2.x and 7.3.x versions where a bug caused them to be read in reverse order.